# Python Numpy Type Error: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, bucket

I tried to write a code for creating a bucket. Since the column to be bucketed has a lot of decimal values and is of `object` datatype, I converted the column into `float` type. After the type conversion and when running the bins the error occurs

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel(r'D:\Practice Files\Anirudh Exercise Skin India.xlsx')
#print(df)

#Conversion of str to int
df['Basepacksize'] = df['Basepacksize'].astype(str).astype(float)

#Pack Ranges/Sachets/Non-Sachets
bins= ['0','10','15','30','50','100']
df1=pd.cut(df['Basepacksize'], bins)
print(df1)
```

I expected it to create a bucket but got this error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main7.py", line 11, in <module>
    df1=pd.cut(df['Basepacksize'], bins)
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 293, in cut
    fac, bins = _bins_to_cuts(
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 444, in _bins_to_cuts
    labels = _format_labels(
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 578, in _format_labels
    precision = _infer_precision(precision, bins)
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 644, in _infer_precision
    levels = [_round_frac(b, precision) for b in bins]
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 644, in <listcomp>    levels = [_round_frac(b, precision) for b in bins]
  File "C:\Users\ani\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py", line 628, in _round_frac
    if not np.isfinite(x) or x == 0:
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Process finished with exit code 1
Improve question
```

Comment: What is `x` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

On this line;

```
if not np.isfinite(x) or x == 0:
```

Datatype of `x` should be a `float`.

If it is any other datatype it will give you error.

Comment: The Datatype used to be object. I have Changed it to float by using this code line given above "df['Basepacksize'] = df['Basepacksize'].astype(str).astype(float)"